# Bitcoin sendfrom and sendtoaddress

Tags: bitcoin-cli, sendtoaddress

I am using bitcoin daemon in my system to get and pass btc to users. So now I want to pass some btc to another users but I can not understand what is the difference between `sendfrom` and `sendtoaddress`. I have read about `sendtoaddress` command in 
http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/sendtoaddress but could not understand where this btc is going from

Answer (score 1):

According to the Bitcoin core developers reference, [SendFrom](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#sendfrom) is deprecated and you should use `SendToAddress` or `SendMany` instead.

Note that `SendFrom` sends from an *account* not from an *address*. The Account feature is being removed from Bitcoin core.

I assume the (HD) wallet rummages around for suitable UTXOs to use as inputs to the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin node is one wallet and `accounts` are its internal accounting system which is deprecated now: https://github.com/bitcoin-dot-org/bitcoin.org/issues/1287

The major issue is account balance can go negative which is "WONTAFIX" https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/2079

I'd recommend using latest Bitcoin [0.17.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.17.0) which has multi wallet features which can isolate each user, further read:

> https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Multi-wallet_RPC_calls
>
> https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/13058

**Edit: (To upgrade from 0.16.3 to 0.17.0)**

Assuming installed [0.16.3](https://bitcoin.org/en/full-node#ubuntu-1604) via `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:bitcoin/bitcoin` I was able to upgrade from 0.16.3 to 0.17.0 successfully by following:

```
cd ~
wget https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.17.0/bitcoin-0.17.0.tar.gz
tar -xvzf bitcoin-0.17.0.tar.gz 
cd bitcoin-0.17.0/

#Install dependencies to compile

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config libssl-dev libevent-dev bsdmainutils git libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev curl
sudo apt install build-essential libtool autotools-dev automake pkg-config libssl-dev libevent-dev bsdmainutils git libdb4.8-dev libdb4.8++-dev curl
sudo apt install libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-chrono-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-test-dev libboost-thread-dev libzmq3-dev

#Compile Bitcoin 0.17.0

./autogen.sh
./configure
make

#sudo worked for me 

sudo make install 

#rebooting was required for me as bitcoind was still showing 0.16.3, after reboot 0.17.0 was shown
```

Comment: thanks for reply! I have already installed 0.16.3 version. but i can't upgrade it to 0.17.0 . Can you send me more details to upgrade it ?

Comment: @YurGasparyan I added details as I tested to upgrade from 0.16.3 to 0.17.0